# Need to form custom request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, custom-code

I am in need to create a custom request in jmeter which looks like the below format:

```
{
"items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "productId": 1234
         }
        {
            "id": "2",
            "productId": 1218
        }
....
}
```

Here I have to generate some random number in between 10-15 and create the id blocks(based on the random number).
Could someone please help how can I form the request accordingly and achieve this in jmeter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which need to send this generated value
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils


   def items = []
   def itemsNo = RandomUtils.nextInt(10, 16)

   1.upto(itemsNo) { id ->
       def productId = RandomUtils.nextInt(1111, 10000)
       def item = [:]
       item.put('id', id as String)
       item.put('productId', productId)
       items.add(item)
   }

   def payload = new JsonBuilder([items: items]).toPrettyString()
   vars.put('payload',payload)
   ```
3. Use `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where you need to refer the generated JSON

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, can we use the csv dataset config to pick the product id's from that file?
If yes, then how to use it in your custom code?

Comment: tried to use the csv dataset variable name in your custom code. But it is picking the same product id value in the same request.

modified code:
1.upto(itemsNo) { id ->
    def productID = ${prodid}
    def item = [:]
    item.put('id', id as String)
    item.put('productID', productID)
    items.add(item)
}


sample output:
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "productID": 1919
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "productID": 1919
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into groovy scripts, only first occurrence will be cached and used, replace your `${prodid}` with `vars.get('prodid'}`. **vars** stand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

Comment: I tried to use `vars.get('prodid')` but still the value is getting same in the request.
`{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "productID": "1919"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "productID": "1919"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: In case of [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) JMeter reads the next value for each user for each iteration, if you want to read all the values in one shot you need to read the file in Groovy, something like: `new File('browser.txt').readLines().get(id)`. More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)